Can't start ActiveMQ Classic on Linux with Java 17
I tried to start the ActiveMQ Classic 5.18.3 by command ./activemq console, but then I got the error:
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to account.jetbrains.com/1.2.3.4:61614

I'm newbie on ActiveMQ, so I don't understand why this relate to account.jetbrains.com?
Anyone have idea on how to overcome this?
I tried with the latest version (6.1.0) but still got the same issue.
The log as below:
[centos@localhost bin]$ ./activemq console
INFO: Loading '/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//bin/env'
INFO: Using java '/home/centos/apps/java-17-openjdk-17.0.6.0.10-2.portable.jdk.el.x86_64/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
INFO: Creating pidfile /home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//data/activemq.pid
Java Runtime: Red Hat, Inc. 17.0.6 /home/centos/apps/java-17-openjdk-17.0.6.0.10-2.portable.jdk.el.x86_64
  Heap sizes: current=67584k  free=61199k  max=1048576k
    JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//conf/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//tmp --add-reads=java.xml=java.logging --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming.spi=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.https://www.protocol.http=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.https://www.protocol.https=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/sun.net.https://www.protocol.jar=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.xml.dom/org.w3c.dom.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.naming.rmi/com.sun.jndi.url.rmi=ALL-UNNAMED -Dactivemq.classpath=/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//conf:/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/ -Dactivemq.base=/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/ -Dactivemq.conf=/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//conf -Dactivemq.data=/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//data -Djolokia.conf=file:/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3//conf/jolokia-access.xml
Extensions classpath:
  [/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/lib,/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/lib/camel,/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/lib/optional,/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/lib/web,/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/data/kahadb]
 INFO | Starting Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/data/kahadb]
 INFO | Starting KahaDBStore
 INFO | Opening MessageDatabase
 INFO | Starting Temp Data Store
 INFO | PListStore:[/home/centos/apps/apache-activemq-5.18.3/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Starting Job Scheduler Store
 INFO | Persistence Adapter successfully started
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.3 (localhost, ID:localhost.localdomain-34109-1711967749078-0:1) is starting
 INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://localhost.localdomain:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector openwire started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://localhost.localdomain:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector amqp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://localhost.localdomain:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector stomp started
 INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://localhost.localdomain:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
 INFO | Connector mqtt started
 INFO | Starting Jetty server
 INFO | Creating Jetty connector
 WARN | mailto:servletcontext@o.e.j.s.servletcontexthandler@6daf7d37{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ (localhost, ID:localhost.localdomain-34109-1711967749078-0:1)
java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to account.jetbrains.com/1.2.3.4:61614
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:349) ~[jetty-server-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:310) ~[jetty-server-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80) ~[jetty-server-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234) ~[jetty-server-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) ~[jetty-util-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:401) ~[jetty-server-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) ~[jetty-util-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer.doStart(WSTransportServer.java:99) ~[activemq-http-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:55) ~[activemq-client-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector.start(TransportConnector.java:266) ~[activemq-broker-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startTransportConnector(BrokerService.java:2732) ~[activemq-broker-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startAllConnectors(BrokerService.java:2625) ~[activemq-broker-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(BrokerService.java:762) ~[activemq-broker-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startBroker(BrokerService.java:724) ~[activemq-broker-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:622) ~[activemq-broker-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:73) ~[activemq-spring-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1930) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1872) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) [spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) [spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) [spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) [spring-beans-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:921) [spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) [spring-context-5.3.30.jar:5.3.30]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64) [xbean-spring-4.24.jar:4.24]
    at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52) [xbean-spring-4.24.jar:4.24]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104) [activemq-spring-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104) [activemq-spring-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67) [activemq-spring-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71) [activemq-broker-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54) [activemq-broker-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87) [activemq-console-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63) [activemq-console-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154) [activemq-console-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63) [activemq-console-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104) [activemq-console-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262) [activemq.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115) [activemq.jar:5.18.3]
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:555) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:337) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:89) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:344) ~[jetty-server-9.4.53.v20231009.jar:9.4.53.v20231009]
    ... 49 more
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.3 (localhost, ID:localhost.localdomain-34109-1711967749078-0:1) is shutting down


Can you paste your activemq.xml?

The broker is attempting to start an embedded instance of Jetty (i.e. HTTP server) and it's attempting to bind that server to the address:port of account.jetbrains.com/1.2.3.4:61614. This should not be happening by default. I assume you've modified your broker configuration to make this happen.

I just download it here: https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/
And then start it without changing anything.

I downloaded the same and when I run activemq console that's not the behavior I see so there must be something in your environment that's causing this.
